# How do I create a new .md file ad get rid of attempts I have made to start afresh?

Tags: git

I am studying data science. I have made several attempts to create a .md text file on which I am supposed to add a secondary heading. How do I do this and how do I get rid of the several attempts I made on git as this is now confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

See "[Markdown Basics - Headings](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics/#headings)"

```
## The second largest heading (an <h2> tag)
```

If you have done your attempts on GitHub directly, it is easier to fix it in a local clone.

Once you have cloned, you can squash your intermediate commit, or you can even, if that `.md` file is supposed to be your first commit:

- remove the `.git`,
- type:

  ```
  git init .
  git add . 
  git commit -m "first commit" 
  git remote add origin https://github.com/yourname/yourrepo.git.
  ```

In both cases, you will have to do a force push:

```
git push -f -u origin master
```

Comment: I cloned the repo file from my github account and was trying to create the .md file on the local repository. I  had not even committed it. But when I ask for git status, I get so much information I get confused. So I wanted to start from scratch. My problem is that when I clone, I do not know where the repo file goes or whether I should create a directory before I clone.

Comment: @CharlesRukuni Can you edit your question with the output of the git status command?

Comment: @CharlesRukuni you don't have to create a folder when you clone: `git clone https://github.com/yourname/yourRepo newFolder`: that will create `newFolder` for you.

Comment: The exercise says: Create a text file called HelloWorld.md
Add the line "## This is a markdown file" (without the quotation marks) to the document (without the quotation marks)
Push the document to the datasciencecoursera repo you created on Github

Comment: I had no problem creating the datasciencecoursera repo on github

Comment: @CharlesRukuni Great, then clone that empty repo, create the file locally and add, commit and push

Comment: @CharlesRukuni follow also https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 to get a feel for those git commands (add, commit, ...)